# Creating multiple networks and looping over them in R

Tags: r, loops, igraph

I'm currently doing research on company interlocks, where I want to analyse their connections with each other for different years. I have so far surveyed my data and created an edge list with multiple attributes, one of which is the time they are connected. Here is some sample data:

```
sample <- data.frame(ID = 1:8, org_ID = c(5,4,1,2,2,2,5,7), mon = c("1998m1", "1998m2","1998m2","1998m2","1999m4","1999m12","2000m1", "2000m12"))
library(igraph)
```

I've used the grep command to group the data into years, since that will be the base of my analysis:

```
yr1998 <- grep('1998', unique(sample$mon), value=TRUE)
yr1999 <- grep('1999', unique(sample$mon), value=TRUE)
yr2000 <- grep('2000', unique(sample$mon), value=TRUE)
```

My original data consists of 15 years and I will calculate multiple measures. I want to create a loop, where the code shown below would go through all years in the analysis, 1998 to 2012. I'm guessing that if I get the general idea right I can add more measures and plot my graphs without having to rewrite this for every time - as far as I understand, this is the principle behind looping and that sounds incredibly handy. :-)

```
##Create graph per year:
# 1998
df.1998 <- sample[sample$mon %in% yr1998,]
g.1998 <- graph.data.frame(d = df.1998, directed = TRUE)
g.1998 <- simplify(df.1998, remove.multiple = FALSE, remove.loops = TRUE)
E(g.1998)$weight <- count_multiple(g.1998)
g.1998

#calculate values
centralization.degree(g.1998)
g.1998$betweenness <- betweenness(g.1998)
```

I've read into both for-loops and the lapply-function but can get neither to work for what I intend. Please note that this is my first project in R and I'm more used to working in Stata, but I'm very eager to learn.

On a sidenote: I am also interested if there is a more elegant way to group my data into 15 graphs. My first attempt was to subset into monthly data frames, but now my research scope has changed to years instead of months. For some reason I managed to write a working loop there.

```
# subsetting into monthly data
#for(j in unique(sample$mon)) {
#  yr <- paste("sample", j, sep = ".")
#  assign(yr, sample[sample$mon==j,])
#}
```

Thanks in advance for taking the time to read this and any answers.

Comment: Not the best solution but think about nested for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should generate a list which contains a graph for each year of data.

```
library(igraph)

sample <- data.frame(ID = 1:8, 
                     org_ID = c(5,4,1,2,2,2,5,7), 
                     mon = c("1998m1", "1998m2","1998m2","1998m2","1999m4","1999m12","2000m1", "2000m12"))

# Add a column for the year
sample$year <- substr(sample$mon, 1, 4)

# Create a function to generate a graph
get.graphs <- function(df){
  g <- graph.data.frame(d = df, directed = TRUE)
  g <- simplify(g, remove.multiple = FALSE, remove.loops = TRUE)
  E(g)$weight <- count_multiple(g)
  g

  #calculate values
  centralization.degree(g)
  g$betweenness <- betweenness(g)

  return(g)
}

# Get a list of dataframes by year
df.list <- split(sample, sample$year)

# Create a list of graphs for each year
graph.list <- lapply(df.list, get.graphs)

# Access an individual graph
graph.list$`1999`
```

Comment: Matt, I can not thank you enough for this - I just adjusted it to my actual data frame and it works like a charm. I'll try to keep the concept of functions in mind as this will save me a lot of work during this project alone!